# Reading a text file and constructing a matrix from it

Tags: pascal, freepascal

I need to construct a matrix; a number of columns and rows are also in the first row of the matrix, I'll make an example so its more clearer.

```
4 3  
1 2 3 
5 6 7 
9 10 8 
1 11 13
```

Where m=4 (number of rows) and n=3 (number of columns)

This is an example of a text file. Is something like this even possible?

```
 Program Feb;

 const
   max=100;

 type
   Matrix=array[1..max,1..max] of integer;

var datoteka:text;
  m,n:integer;
  counter:integer;

begin
  assign(datoteka,'datoteka.txt');
  reset(datoteka);
  while not eoln(datoteka) do
  begin
    read(datoteka, m);
    read(datoteka, n);
  end;
  repeat
    read eoln(n)
  until eof(datoteka) 
  write (m,n);
end.
```

My code isn't a big help, cause I don't know how to write it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, have a look at the code I wrote to do the task, and then look at my explanation below.

```
program Matrixtest;

uses
  sysutils;

var
  NoOfCols,
  NoOfRows : Integer;
  Source : TextFile;
  Matrix : array of array of integer;
  FileName : String;
  Row,
  Col   : Integer; // for-loop iterators to access a single cell of the matrix
  Value : Integer;
begin
  //  First, construct the name of the file defining the matrix
  //  This assumes that the file is in the same folder as this app
  FileName := ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)) + 'MatrixDef.Txt';
  writeln(FileName);  // echo it back to the screen so we can see it

  //  Next, open the file
  Assign(Source, FileName);
  Reset(Source);

  read(Source, NoOfRows, NoOfCols);
  writeln('Cols: ', NoOfCols, 'Rows: ', NoOfRows);
  SetLength(Matrix, NoOfCols, NoOfRows);

  readln(source);  // move to next line in file

  //  Next, read the array data
  for Row := 1 to NoOfRows do begin
    for Col := 1 to NoOfCols do begin
      read(Source, Value);
      Matrix[Col - 1, Row - 1] := Value;
    end;
  end;

  //  Display the array contents
  for Row := 1 to NoOfRows do begin
    for Col := 1 to NoOfCols do begin
      writeln('Row: ', Row, ' contents', Matrix[Col - 1, Row - 1]);
    end;
  end;

  Close(Source);  //  We're done with the file, so close it to release OS resources

  readln;  // this waits until you press a key, so you can read what's been displayed
end.
```

In your program, you can use a two-dimensional array to represent your matrix. Free Pascal supports multi-dimensional arrays; see https://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/Multidimensional_arrays for more information.

This is a complex task, so it helps to know how to do more basic things like  reading an array of a size **known at compile-time** from a text file.

The wrinkle in this task is that you are supposed to read the dimensions (numbers of rows and columns) of the matrix at **run-time** from the file which contains the matrix's contents.

One inefficient way to do this would be to declare the matrix array with huge dimensions, larger than anything you would expect in practice, using the type of array declaration in the Wiki page linked above.

A better way is to use dynamic arrays, whose dimensions you can set at run-time. To use this, you need to know:

1. How to declare a dynamic array in Free Pascal
2. How to set the dimensions of the array at run-time, once you've picked them up from your matrix-definition file (hint: `SetLength` is the way to do this)
3. The fact that a Free Pascal dynamic array is zero-based

The easiest way of managing zero-based arrays is to write your code (in terms of `Row` and `Column` variables) as if the matrix were declared as `array[1..NoOfRows, 1..NoOfColumns]` and subtract one from the array indexes **only** when you actually access the array, as in:

```
Row := 3;
Column := 4;
Value := Matrix[Row - 1, Column - 1];
```

Comment: I did write a program, I know how to define an array. I know how to read text from a file. I can't logically come up with a way to to that. All i need is help how to write a while loop or a until- repeat loop ... or any other method to make it work. I know all of the basics, but i'm not a professional, I'm still a student learning Pascal.

Comment: With respect, your updated q shows that you don't know the correct way to declare an array for this task (see what I said about zero marks).  Anyway, the array (matrix) can be populated by two `for ... do' loops, one nested inside the other.  You could equally well use a `while ... do` loop or a `repeat ... until` one.

Comment: Btw, `while` and `repeat` loops are usually for when you don't know in advance how many iterations you will need, but in your case, you do, because the necessary info is in the file, so you can use `for` loops instead.

Comment: Thank you very much, seems complicated :(. I wasn't exact, I just gave an example there for m and n, number of rows and columns could range from 1 to 100, so i wouldn't know the number of iterations in advance.

Comment: Just to clarify: Perhaps you misunderstood the last comment of @MartynA. With 'knowing in advance' he meant 'at entry to the loop'. He did not mean 'at design time'. So, at entry to the `for loop`, after reading the values in the first row of the file, your program knows exactly how many times to run the loop(s) and in fact **can not change** the loop control variable inside the loop (though *you can break out* of the loop with the 'Break' statement).  `While` and `Repeat` loops **can change** the factors of the continuation condition inside the loop.